# Text being overwritten while saving data to Local storage - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to save all the exceptions coming out from the app in a particular file stored in the local storage. But the problem I'm facing is the text is not being entered in a seperate line but being overwritten on the same line.

A custom file

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class LogCat {

  String data;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<File> writeContent(String text) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString(text);
  }
}
```

Main File

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    LogCat().writeContent('This is coming from main');

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: generateMaterialColor(Palette.primary),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Delete(),
    );
  }
}
```

One more dart file when I'm again writing to the file and the output is being visible as what all data is written in the File.

```
class Delete extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteState createState() => _DeleteState();
}

class _DeleteState extends State<Delete> {

  String data;

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<String> readContent() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      // Returning the contents of the file
      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return
      return 'Error!';
    }
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    LogCat().writeContent('This is from Delete');
    readContent().then((String value) {
      setState(() {
        data = value;
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Log')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          '$data',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm just getting the output printed in the screen as
`This is from Delete` but not like

```
This is coming from main
This is from Delete
```

Comment: Maybe because you're saving both the strings on the same path.. So the previous string gets overwritten

Comment: Yes I do am saving it in the same path cause I'm trying to capture all the exceptions coming from each page and save it in a single file so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `writeAsString` with `FileMode` as write.

The API for `writeAsString` as follows

```dart
Future<File> writeAsString (
    String contents,
    {FileMode mode: FileMode.write,
    Encoding encoding: utf8,
    bool flush: false}
)
```

According to docs.

> By default writeAsString creates the file for writing and truncates the file if it already exists. In order to append the bytes to an existing file, pass FileMode.append as the optional mode parameter.

Your need can be achieved by simply providing the mode parameter as `FileMode.append`. Check out the docs [writeAsString](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/writeAsString.html)

*For the new line*

You can simply add a `\n` to your write string in your `writeContent` code as follows:

```dart
Future<File> writeContent(String text) async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$text\n');
  }
```

Comment: The ```FileMode.append``` did work, but rather than being written in the new line it still is getting written over the previous text as i can see some characters of the previous text as ```The is coming from mainThis is from Delete main``` now.

Comment: So you need a new line to be added with your new message?

Comment: Yeah like i need the messages to come in a new line, not everything in a single line

Comment: Yeah i just added ```\n``` at the end of the line and it worked!

Comment: Haha!! last edit could have been a comment I guess

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the FileMode.append, to solve the overwrite.
Try this:

```
file.writeAsString('text', FileMode.append);
```

Comment: The ```FileMode.append``` did work, but rather than being written in the new line it still is getting written over the previous text as i can see some characters of the previous text as ```The is coming from mainThis is from Delete main``` now.

Comment: I don't know if this works, but you can add "\n" at the end of your text to wrap line